# Payslip Printing in Odoo 11 Giving Error When Printing by a user (Employee) with ReadOnly Access on Payslip

Tags: odoo-11

I want to provide payslip read only access to each employee in Odoo where they can login and print their own payslips. I do not want every employee to generate payslips, only HR Manager / Officers can generate payroll/payslips. Normal users can only view their own payslips and can take the prints outs.

To achieve this I have performed below steps:

1. I have created a new payroll user group "Payroll / Employee" by duplicating "Payroll / Officer" group, in debug mode, and gave readonly access to "Payroll / Employee" on payslip.
2. Then I assigned this group to the user
3. Upon login as Employee, I can see the Payslip option under Payroll
4. When I print the payslip i get below error:

---

```
Error:
Odoo Server Error

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/opt/odoo11-meshsol/odoo/fields.py", line 937, in __get__
    value = record.env.cache.get(record, self)
File "/opt/odoo11-meshsol/odoo/api.py", line 960, in get
    value = self._data[field][record.id][key]
KeyError: (<odoo.sql_db.Cursor object at 0x7f4cd83fe208>, 11)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/opt/odoo11-meshsol/odoo/models.py", line 2646, in _prefetch_field
    result = records.read([f.name for f in fs], load='_classic_write')
File "/opt/odoo11-meshsol/odoo/models.py", line 2572, in read
    fields = self.check_field_access_rights('read', fields)
File "/opt/odoo11-meshsol/odoo/models.py", line 2553, in check_field_access_rights
    (self._description, operation))
odoo.exceptions.AccessError: ('The requested operation cannot be completed due to security restrictions. Please contact your system administrator.\n\n(Document type: Employee, Operation: read)', None)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/opt/odoo11-meshsol/odoo/addons/base/ir/ir_qweb/qweb.py", line 343, in _compiled_fn
    return compiled(self, append, new, options, log)
File "<template>", line 1, in template_1366_11064
File "<template>", line 2, in body_call_content_11063
File "<template>", line 3, in foreach_11062
File "<template>", line 4, in body_call_content_11061
File "/opt/odoo11-meshsol/odoo/addons/base/ir/ir_qweb/ir_qweb.py", line 378, in _get_field
    content = converter.record_to_html(record, field_name, field_options)
File "/opt/odoo11-meshsol/odoo/addons/base/ir/ir_qweb/fields.py", line 106, in record_to_html
    value = record[field_name]
File "/opt/odoo11-meshsol/odoo/models.py", line 4758, in __getitem__
    return self._fields[key].__get__(self, type(self))
File "/opt/odoo11-meshsol/odoo/fields.py", line 941, in __get__
    self.determine_value(record)
File "/opt/odoo11-meshsol/odoo/fields.py", line 1042, in determine_value
    record._prefetch_field(self)
File "/opt/odoo11-meshsol/odoo/models.py", line 2649, in _prefetch_field
    result = self.read([f.name for f in fs], load='_classic_write')
File "/opt/odoo11-meshsol/odoo/models.py", line 2572, in read
    fields = self.check_field_access_rights('read', fields)
File "/opt/odoo11-meshsol/odoo/models.py", line 2553, in check_field_access_rights
    (self._description, operation))
odoo.exceptions.AccessError: ('The requested operation cannot be completed due to security restrictions. Please contact your system administrator.\n\n(Document type: Employee, Operation: read)', None)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/opt/odoo11-meshsol/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 1620, in report_download
    response = self.report_routes(reportname, docids=docids, converter='pdf')
File "/opt/odoo11-meshsol/odoo/http.py", line 515, in response_wrap
    response = f(*args, **kw)
File "/opt/odoo11-meshsol/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 1569, in report_routes
    pdf = report.with_context(context).render_qweb_pdf(docids, data=data)[0]
File "/opt/odoo11-meshsol/odoo/addons/base/ir/ir_actions_report.py", line 628, in render_qweb_pdf
    html = self.with_context(context).render_qweb_html(res_ids, data=data)[0]
File "/opt/odoo11-meshsol/odoo/addons/base/ir/ir_actions_report.py", line 666, in render_qweb_html
    return self.render_template(self.report_name, data), 'html'
File "/opt/odoo11-meshsol/odoo/addons/base/ir/ir_actions_report.py", line 470, in render_template
    return view_obj.render_template(template, values)
File "/opt/odoo11-meshsol/odoo/addons/base/ir/ir_ui_view.py", line 1201, in render_template
    return self.browse(self.get_view_id(template)).render(values, engine)
File "/opt/odoo11-meshsol/addons/website/models/ir_ui_view.py", line 113, in render
    return super(View, self).render(values, engine=engine)
File "/opt/odoo11-meshsol/addons/web_editor/models/ir_ui_view.py", line 27, in render
    return super(IrUiView, self).render(values=values, engine=engine)
File "/opt/odoo11-meshsol/odoo/addons/base/ir/ir_ui_view.py", line 1210, in render
    return self.env[engine].render(self.id, qcontext)
File "/opt/odoo11-meshsol/odoo/addons/base/ir/ir_qweb/ir_qweb.py", line 57, in render
    return super(IrQWeb, self).render(id_or_xml_id, values=values, **context)
File "/opt/odoo11-meshsol/odoo/addons/base/ir/ir_qweb/qweb.py", line 272, in render
    self.compile(template, options)(self, body.append, values or {})
File "/opt/odoo11-meshsol/odoo/addons/base/ir/ir_qweb/qweb.py", line 350, in _compiled_fn
    raise QWebException("Error to render compiling AST", e, path, node and etree.tostring(node[0], encoding='unicode'), name)
odoo.addons.base.ir.ir_qweb.qweb.QWebException: ('The requested operation cannot be completed due to security restrictions. Please contact your system administrator.\n\n(Document type: Employee, Operation: read)', None)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/opt/odoo11-meshsol/odoo/fields.py", line 937, in __get__
    value = record.env.cache.get(record, self)
File "/opt/odoo11-meshsol/odoo/api.py", line 960, in get
    value = self._data[field][record.id][key]
KeyError: (<odoo.sql_db.Cursor object at 0x7f4cd83fe208>, 11)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/opt/odoo11-meshsol/odoo/models.py", line 2646, in _prefetch_field
    result = records.read([f.name for f in fs], load='_classic_write')
File "/opt/odoo11-meshsol/odoo/models.py", line 2572, in read
    fields = self.check_field_access_rights('read', fields)
File "/opt/odoo11-meshsol/odoo/models.py", line 2553, in check_field_access_rights
    (self._description, operation))
odoo.exceptions.AccessError: ('The requested operation cannot be completed due to security restrictions. Please contact your system administrator.\n\n(Document type: Employee, Operation: read)', None)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/opt/odoo11-meshsol/odoo/addons/base/ir/ir_qweb/qweb.py", line 343, in _compiled_fn
    return compiled(self, append, new, options, log)
File "<template>", line 1, in template_1366_11064
File "<template>", line 2, in body_call_content_11063
File "<template>", line 3, in foreach_11062
File "<template>", line 4, in body_call_content_11061
File "/opt/odoo11-meshsol/odoo/addons/base/ir/ir_qweb/ir_qweb.py", line 378, in _get_field
    content = converter.record_to_html(record, field_name, field_options)
File "/opt/odoo11-meshsol/odoo/addons/base/ir/ir_qweb/fields.py", line 106, in record_to_html
    value = record[field_name]
File "/opt/odoo11-meshsol/odoo/models.py", line 4758, in __getitem__
    return self._fields[key].__get__(self, type(self))
File "/opt/odoo11-meshsol/odoo/fields.py", line 941, in __get__
    self.determine_value(record)
File "/opt/odoo11-meshsol/odoo/fields.py", line 1042, in determine_value
    record._prefetch_field(self)
File "/opt/odoo11-meshsol/odoo/models.py", line 2649, in _prefetch_field
    result = self.read([f.name for f in fs], load='_classic_write')
File "/opt/odoo11-meshsol/odoo/models.py", line 2572, in read
    fields = self.check_field_access_rights('read', fields)
File "/opt/odoo11-meshsol/odoo/models.py", line 2553, in check_field_access_rights
    (self._description, operation))
odoo.exceptions.AccessError: ('The requested operation cannot be completed due to security restrictions. Please contact your system administrator.\n\n(Document type: Employee, Operation: read)', None)

Error to render compiling AST
AccessError: ('The requested operation cannot be completed due to security restrictions. Please contact your system administrator.\n\n(Document type: Employee, Operation: read)', None)
Template: 1366
Path: /templates/t/t/t/t/div/table[1]/tr[2]/td[2]/div
Node: <div t-field="o.employee_id.address_home_id" t-options="{&quot;widget&quot;: &quot;contact&quot;, &quot;fields&quot;: [&quot;address&quot;, &quot;name&quot;, &quot;phone&quot;], &quot;no_marker&quot;: True, &quot;phone_icons&quot;: True}"/>
```

---

I would really appreciate if you could help me resolve this issue.

**Screenshots:**

[Payroll / Employee Group Access Rigts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/srjy1.jpg)

[User (Employee) Config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RXvR9.jpg)

Thanks,

Ata

Answer (score 0):

The stack trace shows that while printing pay slip, the user need access to the `o.employee_id.address_home_id`, here `employee_id` is a related field to `hr.employee` object which is a different model from the pay slip model. So the problem is probably in permission to access `hr.employee` model and if you provide sufficient permission to read data from that model to that user, the problem shoul be solved.

UPDATE:

The permission problem is actually due to lack of permission on model `res.partner`, because `employee_id.address_home_id`, here `address_home_id` is also a relational field to comodel `res.partner`, so "Payroll / Employee" group actually need read permission on model `res.partner`.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I already have tried giving read only access to hr.employee model to user group "Payroll / Employee"  but still getting same error.

Comment: Ohh my mistake, the permission problem is actually due to lack of permission on model `res.partner`, because `employee_id.address_home_id`, here `address_home_id` is also a relational field to comodel `res.partner`, so "Payroll / Employee" group actually need read permission on model `res.partner`.

Comment: Unfortunately this did not solve the issue, i provided read only permissions to res.partner but still getting same error :(

Comment: I have observed that employee form is read only for "Payroll / Employee" group. Even though I have provided readonly access to Employee form, but additional information available under tabs (sheets) on employee form are not visible for read only employees. Address information is available under sheet "Private Information" which is not visible for "Payroll / Employee" group. This could be the reason for the error. I'm not sure how can I provide access on address on "Private Information" sheet.

Comment: under user configuration, you will find an Boolean field `Access to Private Addresses`

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response, i'm really new to Odoo and not able to find user configuration, can you please let me know where can I find this. Once again thanks.

Comment: Settings -> Users -> Select your payroll User -> Edit -> Select Access to Private Addresses (Under others section)

Comment: i could help if i had access, this is clearly very simple model access permission issue.

Comment: I have added 2 screenshots at the end of the post, one showing Payroll/Employee Group Access Rights and the other one showing User configuration with Private Information Access enabled. Hope this will help you investigate.